# I cannot submit angular reactive form in a ngb modal Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form in a NgbModal, I can open an initialize the form however when I press submit button, nothing happens.

Here is HTML code;

```
     <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Give your feedback</h4>
        </div>
        <form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="title" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && addForm.controls.title.errors }" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted &&  addForm.controls.title.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf=" addForm.controls.title.errors">* Title is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Comment</label>
                    <textarea type="text" rows="4" cols="50" formControlName="text" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted &&  addForm.controls.text.errors }"></textarea>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted &&  addForm.controls.text.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf=" addForm.controls.text.errors">* Comment is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Rate</label><br>
                    <ngb-rating formControlName="rate"  max="5" [starTemplate]="rate">
                    </ngb-rating>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button style="margin-left: 5px" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger pull-right" (click)="c('cancelled')">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            </form>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #rate let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
        <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100">&#9733;</span>
    </ng-template>

<ng-template #rate let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
    <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100">&#9733;</span>
</ng-template>

<button  *ngIf="authService.currentUserValue" type="button" style="height: 50px" (click)="open(content)" class="btn btn-outline-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal">
        give your feedback
    </button>
```

My open button works fine and also I can close modal, but somehow save is not working. Additionally my onSubmit method is like;

```
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;

  const data = {
      productId:this.currentProduct.productId,
      userId: this.authService.currentUserValue.userId,
      title: this.addForm.controls.title.value,
      text: this.addForm.controls.text.value,
      rating: this.addForm.controls.rating.value,
  };
  this.loading = true;
  this.commentService.addComment(data).subscribe(
      data => {
          this.success = true;
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
      },
      error => {
          this.error = error;
          this.loading = false;
      }
  )
}
```

No error is thrown or no action happens, clicking is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: open function is basically: this.modalService.open(content);

Comment: There are too many dependent components in your code that are unknown. Do you mind creating a minimal sample StackBlitz replicating the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component doesn't know which modal to close. You need to pass the NgbModal reference to the submission function.

```
 <form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(content)">
```

'content' refers to the template reference of the modal.

```
onSubmit(modal: NgbModal) {
    modal.dismiss(); // Add wherever you need
}
```

And just as a heads up, if you...

```
<form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm"> /* Last attribute added */
```

and then create add a ViewChild before the constructor...

```
@ViewChild('f') ngForm: NgForm;
```

you'll be able to access ngForm's submission status by `this.ngForm.submitted` rather then setting them yourself manually. [Angular docs for NgForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm)